# Cakephp - Cannot set Model->id in KeyValue Behavior::beforeSave

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I'm trying to implement a Key/Value behavior based on https://github.com/josegonzalez/cakephp-keyvalue

My behavior will insert new rows into the database for each new key from a form submission, regardless the number of keys, and update existing records if the user_id and key is found in the KeyValue table. I have already linked up the User Model with the KeyValue Model, as well as the behavior.

When the database has no record of a user_id/key, it will insert the new records correctly. However I found that if I am trying to update the existing key-value pairs of a same user, the first two values will be updated correctly but the last value submitted will produce a new record.

After some investigation I found that in the saving loop in `beforeSave()`, even if I assign an ID to the Model in `beforeSave()` with `$Model->id` before returning true, it will not be passed to the `Model->save()` class.

**I'm using cake 2.5.4**

`Model->id` in beforeSave does not pass to `Model->save()` in `lib/Model/Model.php:# 1841`

```
if ($count > 0) {
        $cache = $this->_prepareUpdateFields(array_combine($fields, $values));

        **pr($this->id); //this value is empty**

        if (!empty($this->id)) {
            $this->__safeUpdateMode = true;
            try {
                $success = (bool)$db->update($this, $fields, $values);
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->__safeUpdateMode = false;
                throw $e;
            }
            $this->__safeUpdateMode = false;
        }
```

KeyValueBehavior:

```
public function beforeSave(Model $Model, $options = array()) {
    extract($this->options[$Model->alias]);
    $keys = array_keys($Model->data[$Model->alias]);
    $data = $Model->data;

    if (in_array($fields['key'], $keys) && in_array($fields['value'], $keys)) {
        return true;
    }

    if (isset($data[$Model->alias]) && ! empty($data[$Model->alias])) {
        $dataTemplate = array($Model->alias => array());

        foreach ($data[$Model->alias] as $field => $value) {
            if ($Model->hasField($field)) {
                $dataTemplate[$Model->alias][$field] = $value;
                unset($data[$Model->alias][$field]);
            }
        }

        $index = 0;

        foreach ($data[$Model->alias] as $key => $value) {
            $index ++;
            $insert = $dataTemplate;
            $insert[$Model->alias][$fields['key']] = $key;

            if ($uniqueKeys) {
                $Model->deleteAll(reset($insert));
            }

            $insert[$Model->alias][$fields['value']] = $value;

            //check existing key value      
            $belongsTo = reset($Model->belongsTo);                      
            $existing = $Model->find('first', array(
                'conditions' => array(
                     $belongsTo['foreignKey'] => $insert[$Model->alias][$belongsTo['foreignKey']],
                     $fields['key'] => $insert[$Model->alias][$fields['key']]
                )
            ));



            $Model->create();               
            if(sizeof($existing) > 0){                  
                $existingKV = reset($existing);
                //pr($existingKV);
                $Model->read(null, $existingKV['id']);
            }


            if ($index == count($data[$Model->alias])) {
                // Even if Model->id is set here, it will not be passed to Model->save()
                $Model->id = $existingKV['id'];
                $Model->data = $insert;
                pr($Model); // Model->id is set here but not in Model->save()
                return true;
            } else {
                pr($insert); //Updates correctly
                if (false === $Model->save($insert)) {                  
                    return false;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

UsersController:

```
public function test() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Userdetail->create();
        $this->request->data['Userdetail']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Userdetail->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Userdetail has been saved'));
          //  $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The Userdetail could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    }
   $users = $this->Userdetail->User->find('list');
   $this->set(compact('users'));
}
```

Then I have three sample fields in my View View/Users/test.ctp:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Userdetail');
echo $this->Form->input('field1');
echo $this->Form->input('field2');
echo $this->Form->input('field3');
echo $this->Form->end('submit');
```

To workaround I added another key named "id_holder" to the Model in `beforeSave()`, and edited `Model/Model.php`. But ultimately I don't want to edit the CakePHP core.

**Edit: on the new `saveKeyValues()` method:**

```
public function saveKeyValues(Model $Model, $data){
    if($Model == null || $data == null){
        return false;
    }

    if (isset($data[$Model->alias]) && ! empty($data[$Model->alias])) {
        $dataTemplate = array($Model->alias => array());
        foreach ($data[$Model->alias] as $field => $value) {
            if ($Model->hasField($field)) {
                $dataTemplate[$Model->alias][$field] = $value;
                unset($data[$Model->alias][$field]);
            }
        }
    }

    $belongsTo = reset($Model->belongsTo);
    $index = 0;

    foreach ($data[$Model->alias] as $key => $value) {
        $index++;

        $insert = $dataTemplate;
        $insert[$Model->alias][$this->options[$Model->alias]['fields']['key']] = $key;
        $insert[$Model->alias][$this->options[$Model->alias]['fields']['value']] = $value;
        $insert[$Model->alias][$belongsTo['foreignKey']] = $data[$belongsTo['foreignKey']];
        //check existing key value
        $existing = $Model->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                $belongsTo['foreignKey'] => $data[$belongsTo['foreignKey']],
                $this->options[$Model->alias]['fields']['key'] => $key
            )
        ));

        //Reset for create/update
        $Model->create();
        if(sizeof($existing) > 0){
            $existingKV = reset($existing);
            $Model->read(null, $existingKV['id']);
        }

        if (false === $Model->save($insert)) {
            return false;

        }
        if($index == count($data[$Model->alias])){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This feels like a bad idea to me. You're completely altering what the `save()` function does a model does (single record to multiple update/create transaction). The save operation should be implemented as a behavior method for example `$this->Userdetail->saveKeyValues($this->request->data)`. It would be relatively easy to implement at that point.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini You are right, I have now added a behavior method in the class to handle KeyValues of a model. Updated above. Thanks for the direction.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/thinkingmedia/8b85f275f48ac22814e9